# Mergin Header with Top Bar Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am desperate need of help.

As you can see here is the top bar + header of my website:
[image]

I am also using sticky header, so when I scroll down, the menu remains, but the top bar doesn`t.
The idea is that in the initial position, where the top bar is also visible, I want to somehow merge the left parts of header+top bar, in order to display a bigger logo.

I am not good at php, so I couldn`t come up with any way of doing this in the template.

Any help is welcomed.

Comment: Which theme are you using ?

Comment: its pure theme problem, please debug the code. without any code we will not be able to help

Comment: The them is Accounting by anpsthemes, what code do you want me to send you?

Comment: If its a purchased theme then you may ask help from theme author

Comment: I will try to contact them as well, thank you.